# AJAX success data loading [object Document] in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm having some trouble with an AJAX call in a phonegap app.

I've got an html file with a form in it:

```
<form class="well" name="frmMessage">
  <h4 id="txtToName"></h4>
  <label>Subject</label>
  <input type="text" class="span3" name="txtMsgSubject" />
  <label>Body</label>
  <textarea class="span3" name="txtMsgBody"></textarea>
  <button onClick="message_send(); return false;" type="submit" name="btnSend" class="btn btn-large">Send</button>
</form>
```

I load that form via an AJAX call, on success I inject it into the document

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'templates/message_form.html',
    success: function(data){               
       // display form
       display_message('Compose message below');
       display_setContent(data);
    },
    error: function(x,t,e){
       display_message('Could not load message form');
    }
});
```

This code renders this on the screen:

```
[object Document]
```

... instead of the HTML document I was expecting. I've used the same method for a settings page, which works perfectly:

$.ajax({
       method: 'GET',
       url: 'templates/settings_form.html',
       success: function(data){
           display_setContent(data);
           display_message('Update your settings');
       },
       error: function(x,t,e){
           display_message('Sorry, your settings could not be loaded');
       }
   });

What is going wrong?

If I take out the `form` tag it loads fine, but I'd like to keep that as I'm using bootstrap which needs it. Also, the settings page has it:

```
<h4 id="txtToName"></h4>
<label>Subject</label>
<input type="text" class="span3" name="txtMsgSubject" />
<label>Body</label>
<textarea class="span3" name="txtMsgBody"></textarea>
<button onClick="messages_send(); return false;" type="submit" name="btnSend" class="btn btn-large">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `JSON.stringify(data)`. You can see the full response in there, then you can parse it.

Comment: I've tried dumping that on to the page, but that fails. I've used console.log() and that returns quite a large object, no sign of the HTML in it

Answer (score 0):

inside you ajax call set property

```
dataType: "html"
```

or

```
dataType: "text"
```

and then try setting with display_setContent. Also in your html page you can exclusively mention the content type to "text/html"
Hope this works for you.